# Find all algebraic vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So I'm supposed to find all algebraic vectors of $$R^2$$ such as :

$$\frac{\mathbf{r}}{\lvert\lvert \mathbf{r}\rvert\rvert} = (\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}) $$

I have no idea on how to do this. The only thing that I was able to guess is that this is a unitary vector I think.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: " **All** the algebraic vectors" of $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ ?? That might take a while: do you have an infinite ammount of time for this? Perhaps you want to check what *exactly* is that you need to produce?

Comment: Sorry for taking this much time to respond. My question is pretty clear, it says : "Determine all algebraic vectors of $$R^2$$ r (r is a vector) such as : image that I have posted. Is this an error ?

Comment: You're looking to find an infinite amount of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$; are you sure you've understood the question?

Comment: I wish I understood what the question was asking for. I never saw an exercice of this sort...

Comment: @copper You should *at least* be aware of how little sense your question makes, as there are infinite "algebraic vectors". Either there's some mistake or ommision in the question, or perhaps you miscopied or misunderstood something.

Comment: Though the answer seems pretty trivial, the question does make sense. Yea, there are an infinite number of these vectors but you can classify them all easily, as the answer below shows.

Comment: Ahh!! Now I see ,I think: you want all the alg. vectors $\;r\;$ in the plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ **such that** their normalization is the given one: $$\frac r{\left|r\right|}=\left(\frac12{\sqrt2},\,\frac12\sqrt2\right)$$ , Now this I understand...

Comment: Would a better English translation be "such that" instead of "such as?" Because "such as" has the sense of "for example" whereas "such that" means "requiring that."

Comment: I'm sorry for making this hard to understand. I guess "such that" would be better to use, you're right. But I'm still stuck, a hint would be helpful :/

Comment: @mvw I was typing my comment when you were posting yours so I did not see it. But yes, the French version cleared up the mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;r=(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ s.t.

$$\frac r{\left\|r\right\|}=\left(\frac12\sqrt2,\,\frac12\sqrt2\right)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\,,\,\,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$$

Now:

$$\left\|r\right\|=\left\|(a,b)\right\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies$$

$$\frac r{\left\|r\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(a,b)= \left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\;,\;\;\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$

and thus we have that

$$\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\;,\;\;\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\,,\,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\iff a=b=r\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;r\neq0$$

and thus you want, apparently, $\;(a,b)=r(1,1)\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;r\neq0$

Comment: I swear to god that we never saw something of this sort in my class. Not even remotely. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @copper 
Je vous crois, ne vous inquiétez pas.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the family of vectors $$v=(a,a),\quad a\in\mathbb{R} \quad(a\ne0)$$The modulus of the vector is $||v||=\sqrt{2}a$. Then
$$\frac{v}{||v||}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$
All the vectors you are looking for are $v=(a,a)=a(1,1)$, with $a\in \mathbb{R},\;(a\ne0)$.

Comment: Sorry man, it's the first time that I see a question of this sort. I'm not really sure what to do myself.

Comment: For a given $v=(a,b)$, $||v||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is norm of the vector, right? If it is so, I guess the solution should correct: You are looking for all the vectors pointing in the direction $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. And it is easy to see that these vectors are $v=a(1,1)$, with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (except $a\ne0$)

Answer (score 0):

$r / \lVert r \rVert$ is the direction vector, a unit vector, associated with $r \ne 0$. So all vectors on the line $\alpha (1/\sqrt{2}) (1,1)$ with $\alpha > 0$ are a solution.

E.g. $r = -(1,1) = (-1,-1)$ has $\lvert r \rvert = \sqrt{2}$, and thus
$r / \lvert r \rvert = (-1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})$ is not a solution.